# Unable to create a new conversation in a channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to create a new thread in a Teams Channel a bot has been added to after a specific Dialog step. I have attempted to follow the following sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel, where I use sendMessageToTeamsChannel:

```
        const activity = MessageFactory.text('test') as Activity;
        const ref = await TeamsInfo.sendMessageToTeamsChannel(turnContext, activity, teamsChannelId, process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID);
```

.

I have also attempted creating a new client with Microsoft App credentials and passing conversation params:

```
        const credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID!, process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD!);
        const client = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: serviceUrl });
;
        const conversationParams = {
            bot: channelAccount,
            channelData: {
                channel: {
                    id: teamsChannelId,
                    tenant: tenantId
                }
            },
            isGroup: true,
            activity: message
        } as ConversationParameters;

        const ref = await client.conversations.createConversation(conversationParams);
```

Both fail with a 404 error code:

```
DialogContextError: Conversation not found.
   {
    code: 'ConversationNotFound',
    statusCode: 404,
    request: WebResource {
      streamResponseBody: false,
      url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: [HttpHeaders],
      body: BODY_HERE,
      query: undefined,
      formData: undefined,
      withCredentials: false,
      abortSignal: undefined,
      timeout: 0,
      onUploadProgress: undefined,
      onDownloadProgress: undefined,
      proxySettings: undefined,
      keepAlive: undefined,
      agentSettings: undefined,
      operationSpec: [Object]
    },
    response: {
      body: '{"error":{"code":"ConversationNotFound","message":"Conversation not found."}}',
      headers: [HttpHeaders],
      status: 404
    },
    body: { error: [Object] }
  },
  dialogContext: {
    activeDialog: 'WATERFALL_DIALOG',
    parent: 'sampleDialog',
    stack: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

. Is it not possible to start a new conversation/thread in a channel from a 1-on-1 conversation even if the bot is added to the channel and I have the channelId?

Additional information: I've built this bot using the YoTeams Bot scaffold and it is a Dialog based Bot so I have not exactly copied the sample.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes this is the way I got this to work: create a conversation reference when the bot is added to a channel, save the activityId and conversation in variables in the dialog step, replace the activityId and conversation params in the current context with the activityId and conversation params in the conversation reference, send the message to updated context, then reset the activityId and conversation to the saved variables. I believe this is an old method but I could not get the updated methods in the botframe samples to work for me